# regular expression using C# to find a date

Tags: c#, regex, datetime-format

I try to use regular expression to find a date and time from a log file that looks like this:

```
Dec 25 14:11:03....
```

what is the best way to find them in log file and calculate the date and time
to an absolute value?

I am trying this code but it doesn't find the expression:

```
public long getDateAndgetTimeFromLog(TypeOfProtocols type, string lineOfLog)
{
    long dnt = 0; //variable from date and time.

    switch (type)
    {
        case TypeOfProtocols.PlinkSnifer:
            if (Regex.IsMatch(lineOfLog, @"\d{2}:\d{2}:d{2}"))
            {

            }
            break;
    }
    return dnt;
}
```

Comment: @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" right @t3chb0t

Comment: @Avijit oops... I hit delete instead of edit. I wanted to correct the formatting and it's gone now ;] anyway - I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: your pattern is invalid:

```
@"\d{2}:\d{2}:d{2}"
```

it must be:

```
@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"
```

you missed one backslash `\` before the last `d`

---

Second: I guess by absolute value you mean the `long dnt` variable? If so then you need to parse the date by using one of the overloads and get the [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example like this:

```
string dateString = "Dec 25 14:11:03";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
long ticks = date.Ticks;
```

where:

- `MMM` The abbreviated name of the month.
- `dd` The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
- `HH` The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
- `mm` The minute, from 00 through 59.
- `ss` The second, from 00 through 59.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Third: your current pattern cannot find and capture the entire timestamp so you'll need to extend it to get the date and time parts in one string:

```
string logLine = "Dec 25 14:11:03 Hello world!";
// Your new pattern:
string pattern = @"([a-z]{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})";
Match match = Regex.Match(logLine, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    string dateFormat = "MMM dd HH:mm:ss";
    string dateString = match.Groups[1].Value;
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    long ticks = date.Ticks;
}
```

Currently you are only checking whether a log line contains a timestamp. I've added a `()` catching group to the pattern so you can use the cought value `match.Groups[1].Value` for parsing if a match was found. The index is `1` because there is only one group defined in the pattern. Group at the index `0` always contains the original string (the entire log line in this case).

Comment: yes. Thanks, but after I find it how can I get the absolute date and time value?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: dd is The day of the month, from 01 through 31. however in my log file is 1-31 how can I change the date format to catch the 1-9 ? insted of 01-09?